# How would you separate out a section of a string based on a set of symbols surrounding it(Lua)

Tags: string, lua, concatenation

So I am running into issues separating out a string with parenthesis or any other symbol for that matter, I want to make a function that would have you put in 2 symbols as "border symbols" to contain the section of string I want to capture and then I would have the function look for said symbols and separate out the string. I am wandering if this is even possible, and if so, how I would go about doing this.

Comment: You probably need to escape magic characters with `%` as in `%(`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'plain' string find function so that you don't have to concern yourself with escaping magic characters.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.find

```
-- input:  str,  string to seperate
--         b1,   border symbol 1
--         b2,   border symbol 2
--         incl, true to include the border symbols in the returned value
-- return: sub,  the substring between the border symbols
--               or nil if the border symbols don't appear in str
local function border(str, b1, b2, incl)
  local sub
  local i = str:find(b1, 1, true)    -- using 'plain' means no escaping of magic
  if i == nil then return nil end    --    characters


  local j = str:find(b2, i+1, true)
  if j == nil then return nil end

  if incl then
    sub = str:sub(i, j)
  else
    sub = str:sub(i+1,j-1)
  end
  return sub
end

local test1 = "hello(world)"
local test2 = "(hello] world"
local test3 = "(hello-)(+world)"
local test4 = "hello, world"
print()

print(border(test1, '(', ')', true))
print(border(test1, '(', ')', false),"\n")

print(border(test2, '(', ']', true))
print(border(test2, '(', ']', false),"\n")

print(border(test3, '-', '+', true))
print(border(test3, '-', '+', false),"\n")

print(border(test4, ',', ',', true))
print(border(test4, ',', ',', false),"\n")
```

will output:

```
> lua border.lua 

(world)
world   

(hello]
hello   

-)(+
)(  

nil
nil
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I could find little to no resources on doing something like this.